# chrome html5 video stops autoplay after a second or two

Tags: html, google-chrome, html5-video

I've got an autoplaying video which works well on all browsers, except Chrome - which has apparently disabled autoplay video. I've tried some work arounds, but now it just plays for 1-2 seconds and stops entirely.

Here's my code:

```
<video id="introduction-video" preload="auto" playsinline autoplay muted loop volume="0" poster="/images/videos/video-background.png" width="100%" height="100%">
            <source src="/images/videos/Tasman10seconds.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            <source src="/images/videos/Tasman10seconds.webm" type="video/webm">
            Sorry, your browser does not support HTML5 video.
        </video>
        <script>$(window).on('load',function(){$('#introduction-video').get(0).play();});</script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else having this issue, this worked for me..

```
$(window).bind('load',function(){
    'use strict';
    $('#introduction-video').trigger('play');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, but as a quick followup for anyone who ends up here on a search: **make sure to check your browser extensions**. I was banging my head against this issue in Chrome as well. Then I tried it in incognito mode (where extensions were disabled) and the video played just fine.

I'm not sure which extension was causing the issue. But, that seemed to be the culprit.