# Autoplay video stops after 2 seconds? Used to work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

Alright Ive looked at the other autoplay video issues however my setup does not resemble theirs, and their solutions dont work.

I have a video that USED to autoplay just fine with this-

```
<video preload = 'auto' autoplay muted false data-depth="0.16">
                        <source src="../src/images/intro2.mp4" type="video/mp4"> <!--The first video-->
                </video>
```

the data depth is because its parallax and after checking this is not the issue. On page load, 
I do not change anything in JS regarding this video and I just want it to autoplay like it used to.

I have it muted and preloaded - is this a performance issue? How can I fix/investigate this?

Comment: Have a look at these solutions, there doesn't appear to be much from 2019, but these 2018/2017 results may assist you: [HTML5 Video to play after AJAX page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22179645/html5-video-to-play-after-ajax-page-load) & [chrome html5 video stops autoplay after a second or two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51585771/chrome-html5-video-stops-autoplay-after-a-second-or-two)

Comment: Try `<video id='player' src='../src/images/intro2.mp4' preload='auto' autoplay='true'></video>` instead.

Comment: @StackSlave did not work

Comment: Can you please put your code in snippet? And as well as give video's proper path.

Comment: @EGC tried both and dont work - interesting is the video plays in firefox but not chrome

Comment: @blue I got exactly the same problem, I am wondering if you get chance to fix it in chrome or not?